# Recover contacts etc from old iCloud account after iPhone reset

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, apple-id, contacts

I reset my iPhone 6, meaning I lost all my information, contacts, photos. When my phone turned on again, I had to enter my iCloud, and because I had forgotten my iCloud password, I had to put in a new login and password, and create a new iCloud account.

Unfortunately I have no backup.

I am wondering if there is some way I can recover my contacts and other information from my old iCloud account?

Comment: Start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

You must try and reset your old iCloud accounts password. 
If you have ever synced or made a backup on iTunes on your computer then try to get it back from there.